# Parameterizing SQL queries in Ruby + TinyTDS

Tags: ruby, sql-injection, tiny-tds

I am trying to figure out how to parameterize an SQL string before handing it off to be executed, but sadly I find a lot [of this](http://evilmathemagician.blogspot.com/2011/08/ruby-tutorial-sql-query-to-console-ie.html) on the internet:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE thing LIKE '%#{input}%'"
```

Which is a bad thing...however, parameterizing sql queries is available in the underlying [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/prepared_statements_rdoc.html) library, which is what TinyTDS is built on top of. So I know it's possible. I am just having a hard time figuring it out.

I really wish it could be as simple as [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category%3aRuby):

```
@client = TinyTds::Client.new(
      :adapter => 'sqlserver',
      :host => host,
      :database => db,
      :username => username,
      :password => password)

sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE thing LIKE ?"
safe_sql = @client.prepare(sql, input)
result = @client.execute(safe_sql)
```

I seem to have found something called a [`Dataset`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/adapters/tinytds.rb#L258) class in the sourcecode, which has a prepare method. The question is, how do I use it? Do I need to create another object before handing it off to the `execute()` method in the `@client` object? I couldn't find an `initialize` or a `new` method, so simple instantiation seems like the wrong way to go.

Comment: Is there a `DB` constant available?

Comment: Actually, looking into this, [Sequel has a TinyTDS adapter](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/TinyTDS/Database.html), so I'd just use that. I can't see anything that the TinyTDS gem does that you'd gain from not just using Sequel directly.

Comment: See [this doc on filtering](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html) to see that you can pass the input as you have above to `prepare` and it will automatically make the input safe. See [the doc for SQL users](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html) for how to run SQL directly.

Comment: +1 @iain. Sequel is great and supports TinyTDS nicely. That's how I'd go.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented the Sequel gem with TinyTds as the adapter.   This allows you to parameterize SQL queries. See example below:

```
require "tiny_tds"
require 'sequel' 

DB = Sequel.connect(
    adapter: 'tinytds', 
    host: "dataserver", 
    database: "database", 
    user: "username", 
    password: "password"
)
```

I then was able to make a SQL insert statement with my values parametrized.

```
posts_table = DB[:posts]
posts_table.insert(:author => 'John Smith', :title => 'How to parametrize sql queries')
```

I'm connecting to a MS SQL database.